# `using` Only Some Overloads Of A Base Class

Tags: c++, inheritance, using

Consider a class `b` with two overloaded methods of `foo`:

```
struct b {
    void foo(float) {}
    void foo(const char *) {}
};
```

If I derive `d` `private`ly from `b`, I can [use `using` to expose `b`'s `foo`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration):

```
struct d : private b {
    using b::foo;
};
```

However, this exposes all overloads. Is there a way to expose only one of them (say, the `float` one)? For example, in the following, I'd like the last line to fail compilation:

```
d t;
t.foo(3.13); // d should have this overload
t.foo("hello"); // d shouldn't have this overload
```

---

I tried various ways of writing

```
    using b::<i mean only void foo(float), dammit!>
```

but couldn't get any of them to compile.

Also, obviously it's possible to define in `d` just the required overload calling `b`'s overload

```
struct d : private b {
    void foo(float f) { b::foo(f); }
};
```

but the question is if it's possible to do this tersely with `using` only.

Comment: No. [_](https://youtu.be/YjiTAkKhG28?t=158)

Comment: Why don't you use the real C++ classes?

Comment: @acornagl How is the OP not using real C++ classes? You are aware of the fact that `struct` declares a class, right?

Comment: Of course @Angew ;) but classes have a completely different semantic.

Comment: @acornagl The **only** difference between `struct` and `class` in C++ is that one starts with public access for bases and members, the other one starts with private. Otherwise, they're 100% interchangable. To the point where you can forward-declare `class X`; and then define it as `struct X {};`. Actually even many class-related examples in the C++ standard define them using `struct`.

Comment: @Angew While the standard allows forward-declaring as class and defining as struct, and vice versa, please be aware that due to an unfixable bug in the Microsoft C++ ABI, this may cause linker errors for that environment. (Specifically, structs and classes get mangled differently, so functions can get different names, and it's unfixable because of backwards compatibility.)

Comment: @SebastianRedl Relevant point, thanks for bringing it up. I don't suggest actually using these mixed declarations in practice; I just use them to drive home the point that there is very little distinction between the keywords `struct` and `class` in standard C++.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, that is not possible. A `using` declaration, just like any other declaration, operates on *names.*

`using b::foo;` introduces the *name* `foo` into the declaration's containing scope, such that it refers to whatever `b::foo` refers to. The name `b::foo` refers to a "family" of overloaded functions, so after the using-declaration, the name `foo` refers to the same.

If you want to "publish" only some overloads, you have to do it using the trampoline functions you've shown:

```
struct d : private b {
    void foo(float f) { b::foo(f); }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation that it's name based.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by @Angew in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39633107/4987285), an using declaration introduces names in a namespace.
Because of that, you can't pick only your preferred ones up, but you can still do the opposite and `= delete` the ones you don't want to expose:

```
struct B {
    void f() { }
    void f(int) { }
    void f(int, char) { }
};

struct D: B {
    using B::f;
    void f(int) = delete;
};

int main() {
    D d;
    d.f();
    d.f(0, 'c');
    // this won't work
    // d.f(0);
}
```

This is not exactly what you were looking for, but it is a workaround to obtain almost the same result.

---

It follows a comment made by @Yakk that is worth quoting in the answer:

> Note that a deleted overload is not the same as not having one. If missing a different overload may be selected, while if deleted it may be instead selected and generate an error.

This is right, if the solution above works for the OP mostly depends on the real problem.
I cannot say that, but still this is a viable solution for some cases

Comment: @AmiTavory It is a viable solution as long as the functions to be deleted are a small number. If you have 100 overloads and you want to expose only one or two of them, I'd rather use the mentioned trampoline function and that's all. ;-)

Comment: @AmiTavory No problem, it is not a matter of having an accepted answer or not. I'm here to help and I hope the answer gave you a good hint. That's enough. ;-)